# When did Norman get cured in the anime?

Tags: the-promised-neverland

In the ending slideshow of *The Promised Neverland*, we see a kid playing chess in the hospital. [If he is Norman](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/66303/2516), how did he get cured?