# At the ending of season 2, was that Norman playing chess?

Tags: the-promised-neverland

At the ending of *The Promised Neverland* season 2, we see a kid playing chess.

> [image]

Is it Norman?
But he was out with Emma in the demon world.

Comment: Follow-up question if the premise of this question is true: [When did Norman get cured in the anime?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/66297/2516)